# Are the powers of a convex function convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is convex on $(0,1)$. Are the following true or false? Prove or provide counterexamples.

1) $f^2$ is convex

2) $f^3$ is convex

3) $|f|^3$ is convex

Intuitively, I believe that neither $f^2$ nor $f^3$ will necessarily be convex, but I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample. For $|f|^3$, I am unsure whether it will be convex or not. Clearly, if $f$ is twice differentiable, then $(|f|^3)''$ will be positive, and thus convex. However, if $f$ is not twice differentiable, or if the second derivative equals zero, I am unsure.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = x(x-1)$ works as a counterexample to all of them: it is negative and convex, and it is easy to check that the second derivatives of $f^2,f^3$ and $\lvert f \rvert^3 = -f^3$ are all negative somewhere in the interval.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are saying that $|f|^3=-f^3$. This is not true in general. Is there a particular reason why it must be true in this case?

Comment: This $f$ is negative, so $-f=\lvert f \rvert$.